# Displayport specs: How to interpret and convert to DVI-Dual Link?

Tags: dvi, displayport

I need to drive a Dell 30" display, that is dual link DVI, 1600x2560

I am looking at an AMD board that has 4 mini DP outputs. It says, on the box:

Max DVI resolution: 1920x1200 per output
Max DP resolution: 2560x1600 per output

That Max DP looks like what I need.... if I can get it converted to DVI.

The DP to Dual Link DVI adapters I found all have either poor reviews or max out at 2560x1440.

How to get from this board to my display?

Comment: Is there an option here to get a video card with (at least one) DVI dual link?

Comment: @Psycogeek The multi monitor boards (to support 3 or more displays from a single card) seem to all be DP type interfaces.... from what I have found so far.

Comment: ahh, i think there are some 3s where you would still have to be adapting something, but not any 4s. but it gets complex between how many ports are there vrses how many mon (or res) can be run total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is what I learned:

card specs (this card is ATI Firepro 2460): 4 mini DP, speced at DVI 1920x1200 per output, DP at 2560x1600 per output

monitors: Dell 30" 2560x1600 display (dual dvi) + two 1600x1200 displays (dvi)

Got it all working as follows:

Mini DP port 1: connect to Apple Mini Display Port to Dual Link DVI adapter (note: ACTIVE adapter, requires USB port for addl power!)

Mini DP ports 3 and 4 to the 1600x1200 displays.

All works.

One video board drives the whole rig (and this video board is passive... low power draw!)